# Why do some rows in Cassandra not change?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I try to change some rows most of them change correctly but some of them are not.
I am sure about my partition key and cluster key (I've just one replica).
for example :

```
insert into ks_test.test (id,name,age,point) 
values (399,'amir',20,99844);
```

if the row exist with same data just with different point like : `(399 , 'amir' , 20 , 69874)`
insert query should override point the data I have to see at the end `(399,'amir',20,99844)`

I just try delete and update query but it doesn't work on this row.
It's very weird because most of them change correctly but some of them doesn't.

This is my schema creation :

```
CREATE TABLE ks_test.test(
    id int,
    name varchar,
    age int,
    point int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id,name),age)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (age ASC);
```

Comment: Please update your question with the table schema so we know how the data is partitioned in the table. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, we need to know what the PRIMARY KEY definition is.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the issue, I suspect that your expectation does not match the table's `PRIMARY KEY` definition.

Having said that, we can only speculate at what the problem is because you have not provided all the necessary details, particularly the table's schema.

If you update your original question with:

- the table schema,
- sample input data,
- expected output, and
- minimal steps to replicate the problem,

I'd be happy to look at it again and update my answer. Cheers!

**[UPDATE]** I've tried to replicate the issue you reported using the table schema + data you provided with:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM rowstest ;

 id  | name | age | point
-----+------+-----+-------
 399 | amir |  20 | 69874
```

Then overwrite it with:

```
cqlsh> INSERT INTO rowstest (id, name, age, point) VALUES (399, 'amir', 20, 99844);
```

And the result is exactly as expected:

```
cqlsh> > SELECT * FROM rowstest ;

 id  | name | age | point
-----+------+-----+-------
 399 | amir |  20 | 99844
```

Without detailed steps on how to replicate the issue, all I can say is that there's something wrong in what you're doing so the data isn't getting updated as you expect. Cheers!

Comment: Hello , thanks for your reply .if the problem connected to partition key why after executing query there is no error and razorSQL just said query executed.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your issue based on the information you've provided -- it works for me. Please provide the steps that you're executing to replicate the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think Erick hit the nail on the head. However, the only other time I've seen something like this is when you INSERT with a USING TIMESTAMP statement where the timestamp is in the future. That doesn't look like what you're doing here, but just thought I'd throw it out there.